# How can I fix data frame has no attribute plot

Tags: python, pandas, visualize

```
dd=df.select(df.Color,df.ListPrice.cast("float"))
colordf = dd[['Color','ListPrice']]
colordfgroup = colordf.groupby('Color').mean('ListPrice')
colordfgroup.show()

my_plot = colordfgroup.plot(kind='bar')
```

It shows me that DataFrame has no attribute plot.

All data frame type is a string.

Comment: What is `print (colordfgroup)` after `colordfgroup = colordf.groupby('Color').mean('ListPrice')` ?

Comment: Do you have distinct Color to begin with? Anyway, seems suspicions with string as the return type, in case there is no mean to plot, which it should have still tried to plot with no bars.

Comment: @jezrael It said DataFrame[Color: string, avg(ListPrice): double]

Comment: @Sowmya After I tried colordfgroup.head(15), I show me distinct Color and null value. Which visualize should I plot?

Comment: Could you please check if there is any groupby done for the 'null' value? If yes, then does colordfgroup.plot() discards 'null' values?

Comment: @Sowmya I checked my file.txt. There are null values in the color column. Also, I tried colordfgroup.plot(). It said the data frame has no attribute plot.

Answer (score 0):

I commented the line colordfgroup.show() and corrected mean calculation

```
    dd=df.select(df.Color,df.ListPrice.cast("float"))
    colordf = dd[['Color','ListPrice']]
    colordfgroup = colordf.groupby('Color')['ListPrice'].mean()
    #colordfgroup.show()

    my_plot = colordfgroup.plot(kind='bar')
```

Here is a minimal example

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',  ]
lp     = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 12.0, 22.0, 32.0, 42.0 ]
colordf = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Color': colors, 'ListPrice':lp}, index = [x for x in range(len(colors))])
colordfgroup = colordf.groupby('Color')['ListPrice'].mean()
my_plot = colordfgroup.plot(kind='bar')
```